# Split windows for 4 panels in i3wm

Tags: i3-window-manager, split-window

In default `i3wm` I can split windows only vertical or horizontal. Can I split my 4 windows are like that:

```
|_1_|_2_|
|_3_|_4_|
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use i3 anymore, but as you said, you ‘can split windows only vertical or horizontal.’ So assuming you have the defaults set, to create this grid-like layout, just

1. open your first window (1)
2. open your second window (2)

```
+---+---+
|   |   |
| 1 | 2 |
|   |   |
+---+---+
```

3. switch back to your first window (1) (`MOD + j` focuses left by default)
4. preselect a vertical split (`SUPER + v` splits vertically by default)
5. open your third window (3)

```
+---+---+
| 1 |   |
+---+ 2 |
| 3 |   |
+---+---+
```

6. switch back to your second window (2) (`SUPER + ;` focuses right by default)
7. preselect a horizontal split (`SUPER + v` by default)
8. open your last window (4)

```
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
+---+---+
| 3 | 4 |
+---+---+
```

You have the desired layout.

*(`MOD` is the i3 combination key you use; for example I prefer the Windows (Super) key)*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between `MOD` and `SUPER`. I had trouble figuring it out and I'm sure I'm not the only one.